# SSIS - Log all inserts or updates done to the table

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, sql-update, sql-insert

I was wondering if it is possible to create a SSIS package that would take all inserts and updates that were done to the specific table in SQL Server and write them into a text file.

I watched some videos on youtube but I couldn't find this specific case.

Could anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Change Data Capture (CDC)?  It's pretty fantastic.

Link [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/) to an intro article by Pinal Dave.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express and it doesn't seem to have CDC

Comment: Ahh, in that case you want Change Tracking, which is supported in Express.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this.